# how do you provide variable arguments to swagger open api 3 for servers?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

from the site docs: swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/

you can create variable arguments for parts of the server URL, but when I try the below configuration from the page on my site and pestore (), the selected server URL shows up as:  "https://{region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com",

I want it to show up with the default filled in like:
 https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com

```
  - url: https://{region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
    variables:
      region:
        default: westus
        enum:
          - westus
          - eastus2
          - westcentralus
          - westeurope
          - southeastasia
```

Comment: The computed server URL appears below the server list - https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2BfC.png. Is this not what you see?

Comment: sorry to get back so late, yep that was it. thank you Helen